# Converting double quotes within JSON values to single quotes?

Tags: python, json, list, replace, double-quotes

I have a list of json strings that looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "info": "https://google.com/athens",
    "locationdetails": "Greece"
    ...
    },
    {
    "info": "italytourism.com",
    "locationdetails": "Gardens of "Little Italy" indoors"
    ...
    }
    ...
]
```

Some of the json values in this have double quotes inside of them (such as "Little Italy," and that created an error since in python only single quotes can be used within double quotes (or an escape character). I was wondering what would be the best way to go through this list of json strings and keys and convert the double quotes INSIDE the value string to single quotes. Some people suggested using json.dumps(jsonlist) to fix the problem, but that did not work for me..Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not valid json. You'd need to have those quotes escaped to begin with.

Comment: Are you sure? I have been able to access the key and value like a normal json..but if that's the case, we need to replace the "" within it to single quotes so that it can be a valid json and used in other functions. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Could you share that bit of code that seems to work? Also, I'm not sure there is... regex might work. How do you get this json?

Comment: this was part of another function I wrote: 
`for dict in jsonlist:
        try:
            dict["info"]= "pastes location variable here"
            dict["url"]=urlparse(dict["url"]).hostname
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return jsonlink`

It worked for the json list _until_ it ran into the issue of having double quotes within the value...which is why I was wondering how to replace those. @coldspeed

Comment: So you generated the JSON strings you have above manually, without the `json` library?  If so you are creating a lot of work for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, your example isn't valid JSON.  Using the `json` library, note that the quotes are escaped properly, and the data can be round-tripped from serializing to/from JSON format.

```
import json

data = [
    {
    'info': 'https://google.com/athens',
    'locationdetails': 'Greece'
    },
    {
    'info': 'italytourism.com',
    'locationdetails': 'Gardens of "Little Italy" indoors'
    }
]

j = json.dumps(data,indent=2)
print(j)

data2 = json.loads(j)
print(data2 == data)
```

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "info": "https://google.com/athens", 
>     "locationdetails": "Greece"
>   }, 
>   {
>     "info": "italytourism.com", 
>     "locationdetails": "Gardens of \"Little Italy\" indoors"
>   }
> ]
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx repairs your bad json in the limited example given, but I would not expect it to be robust for all conceivable examples. E.g., it assumes that you only have alphanumeric characters and whitespace in your values, besides the double-quote characters in question.

```
import re
import json

jsonString = """
[
    {
    "info": "https://google.com/athens",
    "locationdetails": "Greece"

    },
    {
    "info": "italytourism.com",
    "locationdetails": "Gardens of "Little Italy" indoors"
    }
]
"""
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'": "([\s\w]*)"([\s\w]+)"([\s\w]*)"(,?)', r'": "\1' + "'" + r'\2' + "'" + r'\3"\4', jsonString))
```